# How to determine from which module a specific function was imported in elixir

Tags: elixir

When multiple external modules are included by calling `use` on some intermediate module, is there an easy way to determine in which module given method is actually defined?

E.g:

```
defmodule ModuleB do
  def method_b do
  end
end    

defmodule ModuleA do
  # imports ModuleB implicitly
  use SomeModuleImportingModuleB

  def method_a
    # how to determine this is ModuleB.method_b?
    method_b
  end
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a solution that works for me, by capturing the function using `&` and then inspecting it:

```
def method_a
  IO.inspect &method_b/0 
  # outputs &ModuleB.method_b
  method_b
end
```

Answer (score 2):

Every module defines an `__info__` function, you can use it to view functions exported by that module:

```
IO.inspect ModuleB.__info__(:exports)
# => [method_b: 0, module_info: 0, module_info: 1, __info__: 1]
```

Please note that when using `use` the module in question might be injecting code directly into the module being defined and creating functions dynamically - this might cause functions to become available that have not been defined in the `used` module.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, however I actually needed this for  the scenario you noted - when `use` imports functions from the other modules...