# Does Elixir support introspection to show function origins?

Tags: elixir

If a module `import`s multiple other modules, it may not be obvious where a given function came from. For example:

```
defmodule Aimable do
  import Camera
  import Gun

  def trigger do
    shoot # which import brought it in?
  end
end
```

I know there are ways to minimize this kind of confusion: good naming, focused modules, targeted imports like `import Gun, only: [:shoot]`, etc.

But if I come across code like this, is there a way to inspect `Aimable` and see the origins of the function `shoot`?

Comment: I'm coming from Ruby, where `Array.instance_method(:reduce).owner` returns `Enumerable`, which tells me where `Array` inherits the method from.

Answer (score 6):

You can do this directly:

```
# from inside the module; IO.inspect(&Aimable.shoot/0) reveals nothing
IO.inspect &shoot/0 #=> &Gun.shoot/0
```

[Check this out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32648894/how-to-determine-from-which-module-a-specific-function-was-imported-in-elixir)

**Also remember that you cannot have same function names with same arity in two different modules and import them both in another module. This will result in ambiguity error when calling that function.**

Another painful way. You can use [function_exported?/3.](http://elixir-lang.org/docs/v1.0/elixir/Kernel.html#function_exported?/3). Specs:

> `function_exported?(atom | tuple, atom, arity) :: boolean`
>
> Returns true if the module is loaded and contains a public function with the given arity, otherwise false.

Examples:

```
function_exported?(Gun,    :shoot, 0) #=> true
function_exported?(Camera, :shoot, 0) #=> false
```

Answer (score 3):

### Use `__ENV__`

As I learned [on another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34510238/does-elixir-support-introspection-to-show-available-functions), the `__ENV__` macros gives access to [various environment info](http://elixir-lang.org/docs/v1.0/elixir/Macro.Env.html#types_details), including `__ENV__.functions` and `__ENV__.macros`.

`__ENV__.functions` returns a list of tuples of modules and the list of functions they provide, like:

```
[{Some.module, [do_stuff: 2]}, {Other.Module, [a_function: 2, a_function: 3]}]
```

You could visually scan this for `shoot`, or write code to search through it.

Answer (score 1):

I am using Elixir 1.1.0 and what you are describing does not seem to be allowed. Here is the script (in aimable.ex):

```
defmodule Gun do
  def shoot do
    IO.puts "Gun Shot"
  end
end

defmodule Camera do
  def shoot do
    IO.puts "Camera Shot"
  end
end

defmodule Aimable do
  import Camera
  import Gun

  def trigger do
    shoot
  end
end
```

Now when I run `iex aimable.ex`, I get a `CompileError`

> Erlang/OTP 18 [erts-7.1] [source] [64-bit] [smp:4:4]
>   [async-threads:10] [hipe] [kernel-poll:false] [dtrace]
>
> ** (CompileError) aimable.ex:18: function shoot/0 imported from both Camera and Gun, call is ambiguous
>       (elixir) src/elixir_dispatch.erl:111: :elixir_dispatch.expand_import/6
>       (elixir) src/elixir_dispatch.erl:82: :elixir_dispatch.dispatch_import/5

Comment: You are correct that it is not possible to import `shoot/0` from more than one module. However, my question is a bit different. Granted, if I'm looking at `Aimable`, I know that `shoot` must come from `Camera` or `Gun` but not both. But how do I know which one, without scanning through the source code? That could be complicated. Consider Phoenix controllers, which `use SomeApp.Web, :controller`, which in turn has its own quoted `import` and `use` directives. Can I introspect to find out where `render` comes from so that I can look up the docs?

Comment: Given that in his answer @coderVidal provided a way to introspect the function in question, I just added my answer for the sake of completeness to emphasize that you cannot import 2 modules that have functions with the same name and arity.

Answer (score 0):

Another potential technique (added for sake of completeness):

```
defmodule Aimable do
  import Camera, :only [shoot: 0]
  import Gun

#etc.
```

or

```
defmodule Aimable do
  import Camera
  import Gun, :only [shoot: 0]

# etc.
```

Then see which one won't compile correctly.

Just another way to accomplish this end.