# Does Elixir support introspection to show available functions?

Tags: elixir

Consider this snippet from [Programming Phoenix](https://pragprog.com/book/phoenix/programming-phoenix):

```
defmodule Rumbl.VideoController do
  use Rumbl.Web, :controller

  def index(conn, _params) do
    videos = Repo.all(Video)
    render(conn, "index.html", videos: videos)
  end

end
```

`index` uses the `render` function, which it got from an import triggered by `use Rumbl.Web, :controller`.

I know that other functions were imported also. But does Elixir provide a way to list them?

**Can I list available functions for the current scope in Elixir?**

Comment: Related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34325206/does-elixir-support-introspection-to-show-function-origins

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can get such information from `__ENV__` macro. Documentation is present for [`Macro.Env` struct](http://elixir-lang.org/docs/stable/elixir/Macro.Env.html) it returns.

The most interesting fields from that struct for you would be `functions` and `macros` that contain a list of currently available functions and macros together with the module they originated from.

Comment: Awesome! In my Phoenix example, `raise inspect(__ENV__.functions)` shows output like `[{Rumbl.Auth, [authenticate_user: 2]}, {Rumbl.Router.Helpers, [page_path: 2, page_path: 3...`